# ExpressionEngine XML export

Tags: xml, wordpress, export, expressionengine

I am trying to export data from ExpressionEngine to Import to Wordpress.
I have been following various examples online, like https://kodegeek.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/export-import-expressionengine-to-wordpress/ or http://www.bettnet.com/moving-expression-engine-1-wordpress/ which kind of work for my purpose.

I am not an ExpressionEngine expert, I understand the basics.

I am stuck on how to export a slideshow which was created in EE via some custom fields.

The slideshow is displayed as follow in the EE template

```
{if "{pg_slideshow:total_rows}" > 0}
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            {pg_slideshow}
            <li>
                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{image}"}
                <img src="{made}" alt="{caption}" />
                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                <p>{caption}</p>
            </li>
            {/pg_slideshow}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {/if}
```

In my export XML template, I can check if a slideshow is created for the post by doing

```
{if "{pg_slideshow:total_rows}" > 0}
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>pg_slideshow</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value>YESTHERE IS SLIDESHOW</wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
 {/if}
```

This works and return YES for some posts.
But my question is how do I loop through the images to insert them as custom field in WP.
What I need is
- Check if there is a slideshow
- If there is one, loop through each image and insert them as custom field with appropriate caption.

I tried various things without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than thought

```
{pg_slideshow}
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>slideshow_img</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{image}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>slideshow_caption</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{caption}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
{/pg_slideshow}
```